# Delete Core Data item from filtered tableview causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableViewController with a SearchBar, displaying a list of countries. The user is able to add their own and also delete them. Normal delete from the tableview works fine but when I filter the list using the uisearchbar and try to delete one of the entries, the delete animation does not work and the system crashes when I select the back button.
Here is my commitEditingStyle code:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

    Country *countryToDelete;
    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
        //get the country object from the filtered results
        countryToDelete = [self.countryResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //delete the selected item from the filtered results
        [self.countryResults removeObject:countryToDelete];
        //delete the row which corresponds to the deleted filtered item
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else {
        countryToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:countryToDelete];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot a bug in your code at first sight. But if you're using CoreData anyway - I recommend you to familiarize with `NSFetchedResultsController`. It's an object that manages continuous fetching/tracking changes to some `ManagedObjects` that match certain criteria. It can be nicely integrated with TableView, giving you remove/add row animations basically for free. You give it a context to fetch data from and a predicate (criteria that must be met by an object to be taken into consideration by the `NSFetchedResultsController`). It then tracks changes made to those objects and gives you convenient API calls for setting up row adding/removing/reloading animations.

Here is a *very* detailed tutorial describing it's usage: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller